# Check if ObservableCollection is valid

Tags: wpf, validation, observablecollection

I have a WPF Dev Express DxGrid that is bound to an ObservableCollection in the following way.

```
Private _FamilyList As New ObservableCollection(Of FamilyRecord)
MyGrid.DataSource = _FamilyList
```

When a user starts to enter information in the grid, I need to be able to check whether they have missed some information making it Invalid.

So, what is the best method of checking that the _FamilyList has no validation errors?

Comment: Hi Anvaka, it's the Dev Express DXGrid. I've updated the description above with this info too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience w/ the DevExpress grid, but on the Xceed WPF DataGridControl there's a property called `UpdateSourceTrigger` which controls when the data source gets updated (when the user is finished editing an entire row, finished editing a cell, or with every key stroke).  I'm sure DevExpress has a similar concept.

This will give you control over *when* the validation happens.  You can put your data validation logic in the `FamilyRecord` class itself.  When you detect an error put the `FamilyRecord` into an error state that will provide a visual cue in the grid.

**EDIT:**

To determine, upon saving, whether any `FamilyRecord` objects in your collection have any errors you'd want something like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {

        ObservableCollection<FamilyRecord> _familyRecords;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _familyRecords = new ObservableCollection<FamilyRecord>();
            _familyRecords.Add(new FamilyRecord(@"Jones", false));
            _familyRecords.Add(new FamilyRecord(@"Smith", true));

            comboBox1.ItemsSource = _familyRecords;
        }

        // save button
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // validate whether any records still have errors before we save.
            if (_familyRecords.Any(f => f.HasErrors))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Please correct your errors!");
            }
        }


    }

    public class FamilyRecord
    {

        public FamilyRecord(string name, bool hasErrors)
        {
            Name = name;
            HasErrors = hasErrors;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool HasErrors { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, I already have validation logic in the FamilyRecord, and when I Add a row in the grid, it highlights the missing info so I can see that the validation is working. I'm just a bit lost knowing how to check that the collection or grid is in a valid state before allowing it to be saved when the Save button is selected.

Comment: Ah, I see.  How about doing a linq query on the ObservableCollection to see if any are in an error state when the button is clicked?